# What does the numbers appended to words in google ngrams data mean?

Tags: nlp, n-gram, google-books

I understand from the [info/download](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html) page, that the format for google ngrams data is

```
ngram TAB year TAB match_count TAB volume_count NEWLINE
```

Here's a small extract from the file that has 1 grams that starts with a:

```
announced.37_VERB 2008 1 1
annually.34 1913 2 2
```

I understand that the _VERB part is POS tagging. However I couldn't find reliable documentation as to what the numbers after period means i.e *.37* or *.34* etc.,
If someone could provide some lead on this it would be of great help for all those getting to started to work on NLP using google ngrams as data source.

Comment: it might be sense information.

Comment: That's awesome @Daniel. I too believe it as a word sense information. I have seen the words like annually.<int>_*. The data was too big for me to analyze it more thoroughly. Your insight helped :) With your permission I will answer my own question and add some related content

Comment: I guess these are just artifacts of e.g. bad OCR or misinterpreted footnotes. There's also an item `annually_ADV    2008    203820  54858` - see how much higher its occurrence count is.

Comment: @router yup sounds good! :)